# Pq o res.innerHTML não atualiza para "Tudo certo até aqui"

Tags: javascript

```
<body>
    <h1>Soma 3 num 5 alunos</h1>
    
    <section>
        <p>Qual o nome do aluno: <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome"></p>
        <p>1º nota: <input type="number" name="n1" id="n1"></p>
        <p>2º nota: <input type="number" name="n2" id="n2"></p>
        <p>3º nota: <input type="number" name="n3" id="n3"></p>
        <br> <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="enviar()">
    </section>
    <br>
    <section>
        <select name="lista" id="lista" size="8"></select>
        <br><br><input type="button" value="Finalizar">
    </section>
    <br>
    <section>
        <div id ='res'> Resposta...</div>
    </section>

    <br><footer>&copy GenesisHenriques</footer>
    <script>
        let nome = document.querySelector('input#nome').value;
        let n1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
        let n2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
        let n3 = document.getElementById('n3').value;
        let res = document.getElementById('div#res');

        function enviar(){
        res.innerHTML = `Certo até aqui`
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você está usando isso:

```
let res = document.getElementById('div#res');
```

**Isso está errado!**

O valor `div#res` é um seletor. Isso funcionaria corretamente se estivesse usando a função `document.querySelector`.

Para usar a função `getElementById`, você deve passar **apenas o nome** do `id` do elemento.

```
 let res = document.getElementById('res');
```

**DICA:** É sempre importante olhar o console do navegador, para saber se existe algum erro sendo exibido. É só apertar F12. Isso ajuda bastante a verificar o que está errado, ao invés de ficar procurando a solução aleatoriamente.